# stristr in csv file, display a row only once

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to search a value in some csv files, and display all the rows containing that search term, with the following code:

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("csv/*.csv") as $file) {
        $filter = explode('/', $file);
        $filter = explode('.',$filter[1]);
        $filter = $filter[0];
        $rowcount = 0;
        $file = fopen($file, "r");
        while (($artext = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
          $line = ++$rowcount;

            foreach($artext as $value){
                if(stristr($value,'marketing')){print_r($artext);echo "<br />";}
            }
        }

        fclose($file);
    }
?>
```

However, one row contains the word 'marketing' multiple times so this row is displayed 4 times (in this case).

How can I make sure that eacht row is displayed only once?

The row in this example (but there are more rows where this happens):

```
Array(
    [0] = > http: //www.marketingmax.nl/ 
    [1] => Marketing Max 
    [2] => 
    [3] => username 
    [4] => password 
    [5] => Vergeet niet uit te loggen bij het beëindigen van je sessie. 
    [6] => Artikels over marketing, marketingcommunicatie, reclame 
    [7] => Kantienberg 
    [8] => BEM 
    [9] => marketing 
    [10] => 
    [11] => 
    [12] => Kluwer 
    [13] => 
    [14] => 
    [15] => Databank 
    [16] => 
    [17] => 
    [18] => 
)
```

UPDATE: Full working code now is:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("csv/*.csv") as $file) {
  $filter = explode('/', $file);
  $filter = explode('.',$filter[1]);
  $filter = $filter[0];
  $rowcount = 0;
  $file = fopen($file, "r");
    while (($artext = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {
      $line = ++$rowcount;
      if(stristr(implode("|", $artext),'marketing')){
      print_r($artext);
      }
    }
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can join the whole array into a single string and then look for the match.

```
if(stristr(implode("|", $artext),'marketing'))
```

Comment: That shows every row (with the searchterm) 19 times. I think I did something wrong.

Comment: You forgot to remove the `foreach` loop. if you use this code then you don't need that loop anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
while (($artext = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {

    $line = ++$rowcount;
    if (array_search('marketing', $artext) !== false)
        print_r($artext);
}
```

If you want case insensitive search use array_map

```
while (($artext = fgetcsv($file)) !== false) {

    $line = ++$rowcount;
    if (array_search('marketing', array_map('strtolower',$artext)) !== false)
        print_r($artext);
}
```

Comment: This does print the row only once, but only one row. Not all the rows that contain the searchterm.

Sorry, I think I didn't clarify that enough in my question